# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql hosts Remote database

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi so I am creating a windows application login page. It is connected to a remote MySQL database.

So after testing, I realised that I was running a VPN. This was when access to the database was still fine.

Now when I run it without the VPN, I get this error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at ConnectToDataBase.Form1.LoginWthPasswordHashFunction() in C:\Users\ee\Dropbox\ConnectToDataBase\ConnectToDataBase\Form1.cs:line 38
```

Could anyone point out my mistake here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my connection string:

```
connectionString="Server=MYSQL5016.myWindowsHosting.com;Database=db_123regis;Uid=a123regis;Pwd=**********"
```

And here is the code where the program attempts to connect to the database:

```
String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
queryStr = "SELECT slowHashSalt FROM userregistration WHERE email=?email ";
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", textBoxUsername.Text);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Can you connect to _MYSQL5016.myWindowsHosting.com_ after you disconnect the VPN? If not, that is the problem

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I was wondering why I can only access the database with my VPN on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different port from default, try this format

> Server=myServerAddress; Port=1234; Database=myDataBase;
>   Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;